# Need a programming algorithm for a tight enclosure around line segments

Tags: algorithm

[image]

I have a list of perhaps hundreds of unsorted 2D line segments at random angles as shown in blue above, and I need to determine the sorted sequence of points a – i from them as shown in red.  Here are some constraints and observations:

- The red polyline sequence a - i forms a tight enclosure of the outer
  points of all the segments.  It's like a convex hull, but "sucked"
  into concavities.  A tight enclosure of the entirety of all segments
  would be a fine solution; I can delete the unused parts.
- An enclosure does exist. The segments are not completely random.
- The y value of one point of each segment is 0, and the other end is a
  point on the enclosure.
- The enclosure cannot cross any line segment or itself.  This also
  means that all segments are on one side of the enclosure polyline.
- There will be either one or two enclosure segments connected to each
  enclosure point a - i.
- The points may be spaced widely differently, not as tidily as shown.
- I should be able to determine point a or i if necessary to start off
  the algorithm.

It seems like starting from a bounding box around all segments and shrinking it to form a tight enclosure would be a reasonable approach, but I can't come up with a decent algorithm.  This will eventually be coded in C#, but an algorithm or pseudo-code would be fine.

Comment: In fact, you would not have to check all permutations, but can get the possible neighbors for each point individually (e.g. `f` could connect only to `c`, `d`, `e` and `g`), then do some most-constrained-first constraint solving to get a valid ordering.

Comment: @tobias_k I may have a hundred or so points and I need to do this hundreds of times, so I think brute force would be unwieldy.  I can't do an elimination on nearest neighbors, either, since the points may be spaced very differently. (edited original post to add this)

Comment: I did not mean nearest neighbors with my second comment, but you could for each point individually check which other points it can connect to without a "red" line crossing a "blue" line. That should reduce the possible orderings considerably, but of course that step alone would be O(n²) (or more, for figuring out the actual crossings).

Comment: The fourth bullet item (*"either one or two [...] connected"*) has to be revised. [In this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrEyZ.png), point x cannot be connected to any other point without crossing a blue line.

Comment: @user3386109 - Your example would violate the third bullet point, where the enclosure is not allowed to cross a segment or itself, but that's not really a constraint on the segment points.  Maybe another way to put it is "no point will be below a crossing of two segments"

Comment: @CarpeCimex So the line segments aren't completely random, but are actually constrained so that an answer exists? If we assume that an answer exists, then if two blue lines cross, they are ordered by comparing the `x` value at the top. Otherwise, they are ordered by the `x` value on the bottom. That allows you to write a comparator that any comparison sort can use.

Comment: @user3386109 - Good point, I just added a clarification. I'll mull over your sorting idea, that may be the key.

Comment: [Counter-example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQwYQ.png) for that idea of ordering by top x if crossing and bottom x if not crossing. That gives ABC, which doesn't work. Must be ACB.

Comment: To compare the order of two segments, you compare by bottom x, and return the opposite if they cross.

Comment: Yes, it works for your counter-example.  The bottom order is BC, but they cross so the returned order is CB.  This breaks for impossible cases as noted in the deleted answer, though.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Yes, sorry, I misunderstood you. Thinking about yours now.

Comment: @CarpeCimex Have you tried the simplest algorithm that may work for your use case? Namely, modifying the gift-wrapping convex-hull algorithm to allow for some concavities when no intersections occur. Note "In two dimensions, the gift wrapping algorithm is similar to the process of winding a string (or wrapping paper) around the set of points.": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_wrapping_algorithm

Comment: @ldog - I'm not sure that's simpler. I considered it, but a convex hull is expensive and then the concavities present a new problem. I think the proposed solution can be done a segment at a time in one pass with one algorithm and without exhaustively checking all other segments.

Comment: It is possible to have co-linear segment end-points that would result in an end-point that would not be reachable unless you allow the enclosure to cross itself (actually it needs to be co-linear itself.) Have you though through all corner-cases with co-linearity? There are many weird cases that can arise.

Comment: @ldog - Good point. This is a special case I'm running into, but it can be handled with 'if' statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

History: this answer is now marked community wiki. The original conjecture was proven wrong by [@dont talk just code](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16759116/dont-talk-just-code). [@Matt Timmermans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5483526/matt-timmermans) provided the current conjecture in a comment under the question.

---

The following conjecture is submitted without proof: To compare the order of two line segments, compare the bottom `x`, and return the opposite if the segments cross.

If the conjecture holds, a comparator can be written for use with any comparison sort. Pseudocode for the comparator:

```
compare(segment A, segment B)
   if A crosses B
      return B.bottom.x - A.bottom.x
   else
      return A.bottom.x - B.bottom.x
```

In the event that two line segments have the same `bottom.x`, their order can be determined by comparing the angles that they make with the x-axis, e.g.

[image]

The segment with the larger angle is first. The `atan2` function can be used to compute the angles.

---

Note that the conjecture definitely does not hold for all possible arrangements. The line segments must be constrained so that a solution exists. Here's an example where a solution does not exist (because C cannot be connected to A or B without crossing a blue line):

[image]

A and B cross, so reversing the x comparison, **A is before B**. C doesn't cross A or B, so comparing the x values at the bottom, **B is before C** and **C is before A**. This creates a rock-paper-scissors situation: **A before B, B before C, and C before A**. Such intransitive comparisons will cause a comparison sort to fail miserably.

Comment: This sure is simple, and I can't find a problem with it on paper.  I will code it up and test it, and tag it as the answer if it holds up.

Comment: Brilliant!  I have this working well enough to see that the algorithm is correct.  Thanks to all who contributed!

Comment: If two segments have the same starting point their order is indeterminate. You can determine the correct order by reversing if illegal segment or envelope crossings result.

Comment: @CarpeCimex Interesting. I hadn't considered segments with the same starting point. I wonder if you can determine the order by comparing the [angles measured from the x-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3Abd.png). Seems like the segment with the larger angle should come first. You can use [the atan2 function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) to compute the angle.

Comment: You beat me to it, I just realized that myself.  That's a much easier way to do it.

Comment: @CarpeCimex Very good! I will amend the answer to include this.